# MySQL 8.0.34 - Optimization of Query to process sections based on variable setting?

Tags: mysql, performance

So we have functions on our system that take dynamic JSON parameters. Since they're functions, we can't build dynamic SQL and have to figure out how to write fast queries that can handle parameter settings within the SQL code itself. For example:

```
DECLARE p_array_source_type smallint DEFAULT JSON_EXTRACT(in_JSON,'$.source_type');
DECLARE p_array_source_record_id int DEFAULT JSON_EXTRACT(in_JSON,'$.source_record_id');
DECLARE p_array_ref_type smallint DEFAULT JSON_EXTRACT(in_JSON,'$.ref_type');
DECLARE p_array_ref_record_id int DEFAULT JSON_EXTRACT(in_JSON,'$.ref_record_id');

    SELECT aa.ID
    FROM association_avatar aa
    WHERE 
    1 = (IF(p_array_source_type IS NULL,1,aa.avatar_source_type_c = p_array_source_type))
    AND
    1 = (IF(p_array_source_record_id IS NULL,1,aa.avatar_source_record_id = p_array_source_record_id))
    AND
    1 = (IF(p_array_ref_type IS NULL,1,aa.avatar_ref_type_c = p_array_ref_type))
    AND
    1 = (IF(p_array_ref_record_id IS NULL,1,aa.avatar_ref_record_id = p_array_ref_record_id))            
    ORDER BY aa.ID DESC
    LIMIT count_limit;
```

The problem here is the query is running the check on ALL potential matches, regardless if a parameter is set.

I wonder, is there a way to write this query in a way where the interpreter will flat out ignore specific matches based on the dynamic value of specific variables?

Once again, since these are functions, we can't use dynamic SQL (which would be optimal for a SP).

Just hoping there's a way to do this...

Comment: What does JSON have to do with this? Are your `p_` parameters actually read from fields of a JSON object? I don't want to make assumptions or guesses, so please show a more complete example of your function and the input to the function.

Comment: In general, since you can't use dynamic SQL in a function, the query must be fixed. You could write the expressions differently (using COALESCE() for example), but one way or the other all the attributes you want to test for must be referenced explicitly.

Comment: I think there could be a clever solution using `JSON_CONTAINS()` but I'd have to see a more complete example of your data and input.

Comment: Hey @BillKarwin! So the p_ values are function variables that are set by JSON entries (NULL if not exists). What it comes down to is I need to figure out how to get the interpreter to ignore specific lookups if a JSON value or variable is set or NULL. Note the p_ values COULD be JSON_EXTRACT (which is what sets the p_ variables). I updated the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that might be more concise. There's no getting away from the requirement that you must specify each column to be tested. But you can eliminate some of the repetitive expressions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(in_JSON JSON) RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  DECLARE count INT;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count
  FROM mytable aa
  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'source_type', aa.avatar_source_type_c,
      'source_record_id', aa.avatar_source_record_id,
      'ref_type', aa.avatar_ref_type_c,
      'ref_record_id', aa.avatar_ref_record_id
    ), in_JSON);

  RETURN count;
END
```

To test this, I changed the function to just count the matches and return the count, because I don't know how you're going to use the result of that query.

As for optimization, this is bound to do a table-scan. I don't think there's a way to index it. But that's true of your query too.

---

Re your comment:

There's no wildcard feature in SQL for comparing many columns in an expression. You have to write out all the columns explicitly that you want to compare.

You will have to do that anyway in your case, because you want to compare each column to a different field from the JSON input. There's no magic that makes it compare the column to a local variable with a similar name.

The only other thing I can suggest is to make the expressions a little more tidy:

```
...

WHERE 
  aa.avatar_source_type_c = COALESCE(p_array_source_type, aa.avatar_source_type_c)
  AND
  aa.avatar_source_record_id = COALESCE(p_array_source_record_id, aa.avatar_source_record_id)
  AND
...
```

This form compares a given column to itself if the `p_` variable is NULL. It does basically the same as in your original code, but it's a little more concise.

---

Frankly, I would not do this in a stored function at all. I would reconsider the whole strategy of how I do the query.

You are probably trying to solve the "how to write a dynamic query in a function" problem when you should be solving the "how to get the result I need in some totally different way" problem.

Comment: So to confirm, there's no way to instruct the interpreter to ignore a comparison/scan based on a variable setting?

Comment: Hey Bill - thanks for your time. All I'm trying to do is write a simple function that can match different data based on the passed parameters (but always return the same structure - the matching is what's dynamic). This function is used by many stored procedures. If it was all hardcoded it would be easy, but the issue is the dynamic nature of things. I'll run some tests on the COALESCE approach. My app is currently using CTEs and doing a UNION of indexes to address the dynamic nature of things, but CTEs are so slow it's painful...

Comment: I understand, and what I'm saying is that you are fixed on the idea that "do it in a function" is the way to do it. You have found that functions cannot do what you want, so do it in a procedure, or forget about procedures and do it in application code. I have written [elsewhere](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-or-not-use-stored-procedures/answer/Bill-Karwin?no_redirect=1) about how lousy MySQL stored routines are in general. I avoid them.